# Check if a certain directory exists on AVD using ADB command

Tags: android-emulator, shell, files

I want to check if a certain directory (e.g. `/data/textdata/`) exists on the AVD using `adb shell`.

I'm following [prolink007's answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10902931/2821954), except this line:

```
DIR_RESULT=$(adb shell ls /data/ | tr -d '\015'|grep '^textdata$')
```

but it goes always into the `then` branch if the directory exist or not. I've also looked for the `adb shell` manual without results.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on an avd and it works for me:

```
ls /data/textdata > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "exists" || echo "not exists"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
DIR_RESULT=$(adb shell if [ -d  "/data/textdata" ]; then echo "exists"; else echo "not exists"; fi; );
```

Comment: does not work. it says "exist.sh: command substitution: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
exist.sh: command substitution: line 4: `then echo "exists"; else echo "not exists"; fi; '".
I think is how the command is structured: if statement should not be there (in my opinion)

Comment: the command of prolink007 now works: i was wrong in the command copy.

Comment: I found a solution which works for me. See my second answer.